# drupal phptemplate_menu_tree

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am using Drupal 7, I am trying to test phptemplate_menu_tree, I created a file named, template.php and add following:

```
<?php
// $Id: template.php,v 1.01 2011/2/24 12:47:27 dries Exp $

function phptemplate_menu_tree($variables) {
    return '<ul> <li> test </li> </ul>';
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: When something is *not working*, you should always explain what you mean by *not working* : do you get an error message ? is your function not called ? any information you can give might help us help you ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears in drupal 7, they have dropped the engine_theme (phptemplate_menu_tree) hook. renaming the engine_theme hook to template-name_theme (mytemplate_menu_tree) hook make it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the theme registry with devel.module or by resaving the form at admin/build/themes?

Comment: what do you mean by resaving the form?

Comment: Well exactly that, save the theme configuration. But you are right, the problem is/was the phptemplate prefix.